# Is it possible to create a method which returns a key of entity by reference in C# with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

Let us assume there are two assemblies - Core and Infrastructure. In the first one there are interfaces and models. It represents the domain model and contains business logic. Models are built on abstractions - just interface methods are used.

For instance:

```
public interface INotificationService
{
   void Notify(User user, int modelId);
}

public interface IAuthorizationService
{
   void IsAuthorized(User user);
}

public interface IPersistenceService
{
   int AddSomeEntity(SomeModel model);
   void SaveChanges();
}

public interface ISomeModelManagementService
{
   void AddSomeModelAndNotify(User user, SomeModel model);
}

public class SomeModelManagementService : ISomeModelManagementService
{
   //Here would be constructor injection of INotificationService, IAuthorizationService and IPersistenceService

   void AddSomeModelAndNotify(User user, SomeModel model)
   {
      if(authorizationService.IsAuthorized(user))
      {
         int id = persistenceService.AddSomeEntity(model);
         persistenceService.SaveChanges();
         notificationService.Notify(user,id);
      }
      else
      {
         throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
   }
}
```

All of the code above would reside in the Core assembly and have no reference to the implementation of the interfaces (except the `ISomeModelManagementService`).

In the Infrastructure assembly on the other hand the implementation of infrastructure dependent concerns would reside. There will be for example code responsible for sending e-mails by `EMailNotificationService` or mapping and persisting Core models in a database by `DbPersistenceService`.

The problem I'm facing is with this method:

```
int AddSomeEntity(SomeModel model);
```

I want to achieve batch `SaveChanges` and not to implement saving entities right after each command (insert/update/delete queries). The problem is with inserting new entities with Entity Framework. EF will update its model and return primary key after `SaveChanges` method is executed on the DbContext.

I've tried to pass parameter by reference, but it's not updated after `SaveChanges`.

It's possible to do this with `dynamic` type returned instead of int, so insert commands / add methods would return database model (not core model) and then there's possibility to get id of it after `SaveChanges` execution, but it's a dirty solution.

**Is it possible for a reference to Entity Framework key to be returned by a method?**

**Is there any possibility to update returned id after `SaveChanges` execution?**

```
int id = persistenceService.AddSomeEntity(model);
persistenceService.SaveChanges();
//Now I'd like to have id updated with the database key value
```

Comment: So, if you return the entity after `Add`, the `Id` wont get updated after `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: If I return `databaseModel.Id`, where `Id` is int it won't be updated after `SaveChanges` call. Even if I do the trick with passing `ref int id` and assigning `databaseModel.Id` to the parameter passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to return a wrapper for the id. Since the wrapper is a reference type it should update Id after `SaveChanges()`.

```
// Interface for entities that only contains id.
public interface IIdentifiableEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public interface INotificationService
{
   void Notify(User user, IIdentifiableEntity entity);
}

public interface IAuthorizationService
{
   void IsAuthorized(User user);
}

public interface IPersistenceService
{
   // Return the entity as a interface here...
   IIdentifiableEntity AddSomeEntity(SomeModel model);
   void SaveChanges();
}

public interface ISomeModelManagementService
{
   void AddSomeModelAndNotify(User user, SomeModel model);
}

public class SomeModelManagementService : ISomeModelManagementService
{
   //Here would be constructor injection of INotificationService, IAuthorizationService and IPersistenceService

   void AddSomeModelAndNotify(User user, SomeModel model)
   {
      if(authorizationService.IsAuthorized(user))
      {
         IIdentifiableEntity entity = persistenceService.AddSomeEntity(model);
         persistenceService.SaveChanges();
         // Pass reference entity to Notify.
         notificationService.Notify(user,entity);
      }
      else
      {
         throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
   }
}
```

Then your entities would have to implement the interface `IIdentifiableEntity`. I think that could be a more elegant solution than using `dynamic`. The positive thing is that it's a very small interface and it doesn't really expose the entity that much (except for the `Id`). The downside is that your entity leaves the scope of IPersistenceService, which may not be what you want.

A sample implementation would be:

```
public class PersistentCustomerService : IPersistenceService
{
   public IIdentifiableEntity AddSomeEntity(Customer model)
   {
      var result = _context.Customers.Add(model);
      return result;
   }
}

public class Customer : IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```